# failure of title by function - oop

Tags: php

This is how I have build my page up in OOP now after I have learned it.

This is how I would like the right title for `h1` and title to front

But I lay it on the front page I get the error:

In my error log:

> [20-Apr-2014 01:17:16 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Using $this
>   when not in object context in
>   /home/jesperbo/public_html/blabla.com/index.php on line 17

**index.php**

```
<?php
include("inc/incphp-f.php");
?>
<!--- more code her --->
    <title>
        <?php
            $this->indextitle;
        ?>
    </title>
<!--- More code her --->
```

Where I get all my php files and information is in `incphp-f.php here & my function:

```
    if(IN_DEBUG_MODE){
    ini_set("display_startup_errors", "on");
    ini_set("display_errors", "on");
    ini_set("html_errors", "false");
    error_reporting(-1); // -1 viser alle slags fejl beskeder
    ini_set("ignore_repeated_errors", 0);
}
else{
    error_reporting(0);
}

class mebe
{
    public $indextitle = "Hello world";

//more php here after 
}
```

Why it makes the mistake as it describes?

Answer (score 0):

The error states:

> [20-Apr-2014 01:17:16 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error: Using $this when
>   not in object context in
>   /home/jesperbo/public_html/blabla.com/index.php on line 17

You are attempting to use `$this` when not within the scope of the class.  That’s not going to work. You can only use `$this` within the class structure itself. Try this instead in `index.php`:

```
<?php
include("inc/incphp-f.php");
$mebe_class = new mebe();
?>
<!--- more code her --->
    <title>
        <?php
            $mebe_class->indextitle;
        ?>
    </title>
<!--- More code her --->
```

The main difference is here I am instantiating the class via `$mebe_class = new mebe();` and then using that to call the `indextitle` value via `$mebe_class->indextitle;`

Comment: Now seems the url of the page only